# Time Complexity of breadth first search with adjacency matrix representation?

Tags: breadth-first-search, adjacency-matrix

In bfs we have to look up each node and for each node we have to look all elements of row.Doesn't this require O(V^2)(number of elements in adjacency matrix) time and hence for adjacency matrix shouldn't total time be O(V^2+E).

Comment: That's correct. Do you have a reason to believe otherwise?

Comment: @templatetypedef These:[link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search),[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553676/time-complexity-of-bfs-using-graph-reperesentation)

Comment: The Wikipedia link assumes an adjacency list, not an adjacency matrix. That SO link is just wrong. Your analysis is correct.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The complexity of BFS implemented using an Adjacency Matrix will be O(|V|<sup>2</sup>). This is mainly because every time we want to find what are the edges adjacent to a given vertex 'U', we would have to traverse the whole array AdjacencyMatrix[U], which is off course of length |V|.

Imagine the BFS progressing as frontiers. You take a starting vertex S, which is at level - 0. All the adjacent vertices are at level - 1. Then, we mark all the adjacent vertices of all vertices at level - 1, which don't have a level, to level - 2. So, every vertex will belong to one frontier (or level) only. And when an element is in a frontier, we check once for its adjacent vertices, which takes O(|V|) time. As, the frontier covers |V| elements over the course of the algorithm, the total time would become O(|V| * |V|) which is O(|V|<sup>2</sup>).

The complexity difference in BFS when implemented by Adjacency Lists and Matrix occurs due to this fact that in Adjacency Matrix, to tell which nodes are adjacent to a given vertex, we take O(|V|) time, irrespective of edges. Whereas, in Adjacency List, it is immediately available to us, takes time proportional to adjacent vertices itself, which on summation over all vertices |V| is |E|. So, BFS by Adjacency List gives O(|V| + |E|).

I hope my answer has helped you, if it did, let me know...! ☺