# Complexity of BFS if there is only nodes and their children

Tags: algorithm, graph

Complexity of breath-first-search depends on the [graph representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553676/what-is-time-complexity-of-bfs-depending-on-the-representation-of-the-graph).

But what is the graph represented as a list of nodes. And each node has a list of neighbors:

```
[Node0{[1, 2]}, Node1{[2]}, Node2{[3]}, Node2{[]}]
```

Can we say that the complexity in this case is O(E * Neighbors), where Neighbors is a maximum len of **{[1, 2]}**, **{[2]}**, **{[3]}** from the above example?

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is an adjacency list. The time complexity for it is O(|| + ||). You *can* express it with a maximum branching factor  as you suggest, but then || = O(||.) and so the overall complexity would be O(||.), not O(||.F).

It is essential to have || in there, as we can imagine a disconnected graph with 100 nodes and maybe just one edge somewhere. You would still have to visit those 100 nodes to see in the adjacency list whether they have neighbors.